# How to bend maple for window sill restoration

Tags: bending, steam-bending

We're remodeling a bathroom in a house built in 1920 and we're trying to stay (mostly) true to the original design. The thing we love most about this house is the woodwork. It's simple but very elegant.

The biggest problem with the bathroom remodel has been the lead paint on the trim around the window and doors.  We want to do stain and varnish instead (like the rest of the house [even if it was originally painted - though it had been halfheartedly redone numerous times based on evidence from our demo, so it's hard to tell what it was like originally]).  After trying and failing with stripping the wood, I'm putting my dad's hand-me-down tools and my novice/mediocre carpentry skills to task.  So I'm basically remaking all the pieces of the window.  All the cuts are very simple and straightforward except when I got to the sill...

As with any other window sill, it slopes outward, but I was surprised to notice that the top piece of the sill curves from level to sloped!

My dad originally surmised that it actually had sagged over time, but when I looked closer, the cuts of the "wings" seem to go with the bend (though perhaps I'm mistaken).

I bought Maple boards at Lowe's yesterday and was duplicating all the pieces to later stain, but I'm not sure how to duplicate this.  Was the sill cut this way?  Did they "bend" it somehow?  How can I reproduce this?

[image: sill from top]
[image: sill vertical from end]

Comment: I have never seen such a bend in a sill. It is maybe not original, wood could have bent naturally over a long time but if all are the same I think unlikely. If you want to recreate feature, it is very easy to get most boards to cup haha!

Comment: Not directly what you asked about but how did your stripping efforts fail? Was the stripper not up to the job (didn't touch the paint) or it was just too slow getting through all the layers? Modern non-chloromethane strippers are unfortunately somewhat notorious for being slow and/or ineffective on some paints and finishes (seemingly worse the more green and/or non-toxic they purport to be!) I'm asking partly out of curiosity but also because if you can strip successfully they you can simply re-use your old sills and won't need to worry about how – or whether to – recreate their shape. [contd]

Comment: We can speculate about whether this was an intentional feature or not, and while I initially thought it was possible (if unlikely) the matching curve on the underside makes me strongly suspect not. Instead I think they've crowned over time; or cupped on the underside is probably a better way of describing it. Particularly if they were painted repeatedly on top but the undersides were largely ignored over the decades I think this becomes more likely, as the underside would then be more subject to water ingress/egress, leading to shrinkage due to 'compression set'.

Comment: The cut angle you're seeing is probably to match the original window sill that would have been mounted on a slight angle to help water and debris drain outside rather than inside  originally rather than the wood being curved. The standard angle is 14 degrees I believe IIRC.

Comment: @Graphus - My wife was in charge of the stripping and she was the one who complained about it. While I was sure it was mainly something that I could have better success with if I tried it (and I indicated to her that I could give it a shot), she stated that her concern was that she didn't trust stripping would remove all the lead. And frankly, knowing how she is with paranioa about stuff like that, my offering to remake them was mainly for her piece of mind, though I still plan to strip the doors themselves, since those would be much more difficult to remake.

Comment: @Graphus - ...and your explanation of the cupping makes sense. I'll look closer at other windows in the house that are stained/varnished instead of painted to see if they also curve.

Answer (score 3):

Like in the comments, to me that isn't the original intention, but years of aging.  wood bends and cups and twists.   You have gravity you have paint on one side, but the bottom  not so much, so weather and rot have softened it allowing it to cup or sag (take your pick).  I've worked on several old homes and that is just one of the things age and weather does to wood.

I cut and dry my own lumber and I have plenty that naturally cup like that and then I have lots of work to 'fix' the problem.  I would go with the straight boards and I think you'll be happy with how sharp it will look.

Comment: The wood is still very strong and it's the indoor portion of the sill. You may be right that it adopted the shape over time, perhaps from leaning or sitting on the sill, but I may survey other windows in the house so see if they also bend or are at the angle of the graded sill below that top piece. My dad actually suggested that I could use a wedge piece to create a flat/level surface on this inner portion of the sill...

Comment: If that's the inside, then I'd seriously suspect that it's bent from things or people sitting on it.

Comment: @hepcat72 being on the inside makes it even more believable, that it was bent from people/things sitting on it!

Comment: Definitely cannot discount that. We've never sat or leaned on that sill, since we've only owned the house since 2017, though I am curious to inspect other sills in the house for levelness & curve, when I get home. I did look at other sills in the house last weekend to assess the edge shape and I did note (to my surprise) that that sill in the bathroom had a differently routed edge, so maybe it's not even original.

Comment: @hepcat72  and bathrooms have the added stresses of being in a (periodically) humid room.  can almost be as bad as being outside.  Wouldn't doubt it has been replaced as least once in the last 100 years.